# Pull data from external JSON API and display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

What I'm trying to do is pull some gaming stats from an external JSON data link and display them in a HTML file.

If you visit - https://www.easports.com/fifa/api/fifa16-ps4/stats/fut/jamezaus92

You will see it displays

```
{"data":{"bestDivision":2,"bestPoints":21,"titlesWon":10,"promotions":2,"relegations":4,"goalsScored":458,"goalsAgainst":364,"gamesPlayed":202,"seasonsPlayed":22,"record":{"wins":103,"ties":34,"losses":65},"passSuccess":77,"averagePossession":51}}
```

In the URL described above you will notice the end part is "jamezaus92" if you replace that with any gamertag the data results will change based on that persons stats. I'm trying to create a HTML file where you can simply type in the gamertag and it will display the stats in a table (which I will then later style with css).

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: yes.it's possible.

Comment: Could you please help me out by putting the required code into a jsfiddle so I can see an example? Cheers

Comment: You are asking us to write code for you. This is not the way SO works.

Comment: Not at all, just an example so I have something to base the rest off. I have seen many posts where people have made example jsfiddle for people.

Comment: There are already tons of examples aswell as on SO as elsewhere

Comment: I have literally searched on here for days now, could you at least point me to an example then please?

Comment: Your url is CORS blocked, hard to make a fiddle with

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting JSON data from a remote source,

```
jQuery.getJSON('/Your/Url/Here');
```

does not work.
Instead, you need to use **CORS** as other commenters said.
Here is a nice [CORS Tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for you to start.